# How to bind Knockout model data to Multiple tables

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am using knockout binding to bind some data into html tables. My knockout view Model had multiple products and each product will have multiple chars. I want to display the products in one table and when i select the link "show chars" it should display the corresponding chars in below table.

This is my View Model

```
var ProductViewModel = function(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    this.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
    this.addItem = function() {
        if (this.itemToAdd() != "") {
            this.items.push(this.itemToAdd()); 
            this.itemToAdd(""); 
        }
    }.bind(this);
};
```

And this is my html tables

```
<div id="productTable">
        <table  class="ui-responsive table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th >Product Name</th>
                    <th >Description</th>
                    <th >Parent?</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="pBody" data-bind="foreach: items">
                <tr class="success" >
                    <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span>

                    </td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: desc"></span>

                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#" onclick="showChars();return false;">show chars</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="productChars">
    <div id="productCharTable">
        <table  class="ui-responsive table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th >Char Name</th>
                    <th >Description</th>
                    <th >Length</th>
                    <th >Type</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="pBody" data-bind="foreach: $data['chars']">
                <tr class="success">
                    <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>asdf asdfasdf</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>String</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I am able to bind the products into first table. But for characteristics i am not sure how to achieve the same.

Could someone please help me in figuring out how to achieve the same.

Here is the jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/sirisha_k/0Ln7h2bo/7/

Comment: something like this let us know https://jsfiddle.net/0Ln7h2bo/8/ (i hard coded to index 0 to show o/p). cheers

Comment: Shouldn't the chars table be a nested table?

Comment: @WayneEllery i believe it should be . clarity from OP would be great

Comment: @supercool "data-bind: with" thts what i was looking for . Thanks :-)

Comment: @sirisha Your entire approach goes against the very basic usage principles of knockout. If you want to use knockout, all that jQuery event binding and all that modifying/keeping data outside of viewmodels needs to go. If you want to use jQuery, then kick out knockout. You shouldn't use both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @supercool pointed out you can use "data-bind='with selectedItem'" to populate the second table with chars data. For that you need to add one more item into your model called selectedItem and every time you select or add a row, you point the selectedItem to that elementdata. And use "data-bind='with selecteItem'" for second table.

```
var ProductViewModel = function(items) {
this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
this.selectedItem = ko.observableArray();
this.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
this.addItem = function() {
    if (this.itemToAdd() != "") {
        this.items.push(this.itemToAdd()); 
        this.itemToAdd(""); 
    }
}.bind(this);
```

};

and on row select call some function selectedItem($data) where $data refers to the current item.

then set that data to selectedItem in model.

```
function selectedItem(prod){
    ProductViewModel.selectedItem(prod);
}
```